# Drupal 7 to D7 Migration

Tags: 7, migrations

I wan to migrate taxonomy terms from a D7 install to another.
The taxonomy terms have fields added to them and also translations.
Drupal Migration module would be the only option?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv) module. I used it once, works great...

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using the Feeds module for this. Maybe [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1542294) article can help.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these following modules would help you to migrate your taxonomies:

- [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features)
- [Taxonomy CSV import/export](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_csv)
- [Data export import](https://www.drupal.org/project/data_export_import)
- [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds)

Here is an [article](https://www.drupal.org/node/1819708) that explain how to do it without a module (manually).